# name a variable after the string value of another variable

Tags: javascript

Let's say that be have two variables

```
var variable = "paypay";
var value = "this is the value of paypay!";
```

With the info above, is there a way to make `paypay = "this is the value of paypay!"`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can put it in a dictionary:

```
var obj = {};
obj[variable] = value;
```

Then `obj.paypay` is a variable which is now `"this is the value of payday!"`.

Comment: `window[variable]=value;` will also work without the need of an object. so you can use `paypay` without having `obj.`paypay

Answer (score 1):

```
var variable = "paypay";
var value = "this is the value of paypay!";
```

Some possibilities

```
var parent = {};

parent.variable  = value;  // this is the value of paypay!
parent[variable] = value;  // this is the value of paypay!
parent["paypay"] = value;  // this is the value of paypay!
parent.paypay    = value;  // this is the value of paypay!
var "paypay"     = value;  // error Unexpected string
var  paypay      = value;  // this is the value of paypay!
```

Comment: Why not `var paypay` then? What's the point of `parent` here?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you are properly scoped into a closure or otherwise... then you can cheat and kinda use the "this";

Example:

```
this[variable] = value;
console.log(variable);
```

Comment: But in seriousness, I'd go with ergonaut's suggestion, and stuff it into an object, probably safer than playing with "this" if you're at your current Javascript comfort level.

Answer (score 0):

```
eval("var " + variable + "=" + value);
```

that is a solution even if using eval() function is not always recommended.

Comment: you're missing a space after `"var"`